# Connect Local Host from Web Service

Tags: webserver

I have a Laptop, with msSql sever 2005, and it is connected to my Wifi router which gets the internet. So My laptop get connected to internet. But I need to access my msSql Sever from internet to connect my webpage which I made using ASP.Net.

Please Help me... And please give a solution for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need your IP adress to connect, then open the SQL-Port in your router. (default is `3306`)
When you connect to the server just use your current ip adress. 
Maybe you want a static ip or something like http://dyndns.org

Answer (score 0):

you want to write web service and host that service in sql machine

Comment: No, I have already created the webpage I can use the web services within my local host only. But I need to connect it from internet.

Answer (score 0):

First setup a static IP address on your laptop and after that you need to set up port forwarding in your router. This process differs slightly depending on your routers manufacturer and model.

After this is set up properly make sure that SQL Servers port is open on your laptops firewall.

By using Dynamic DNS you can point to your possibly changing IP address with static name so you don't have to change this constantly in your connection string.

Comment: Btw, it might not be wise to open SQL Server default port (1433) to Internet because of attacks. At least change it to something else. A better solution would be to use VPN even if it takes bit more work.